# IE problem with CSS file

Tags: css, internet-explorer

After the upload of a new site version to the Production environment - the site is displayed incorrectly in IE, tested versions 6 and 8.

While on the local version of the site (UAT environment) everything is fine.

After the short investigation I found out that IE just changes the CSS file itslef. It is starting from ~line 1740 with the follwing:

in the correct CSS version:

```
   .add-topic-form .title,
   .add-topic-form .tags,
   .add-topic-form .original_author,
   .add-topic-form .original_link,
   .add-topic-form .link-url {
     margin-top: 5px;
     width: 95%;
   }

   .add-topic-form .poll-day,
   .add-topic-form .file {
     margin-top:5px;
   }

   .add-topic-form .file {
     display: block;
   }

   .add-topic-form .error {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     background-color: #FFE6E6;
     padding: 20px;
     text-align: center;
   }
```

in the CSS version I download through the IE I get:

```
   .add-topic-form .title,
   .add-topic-form .tags,
   .add-topic-form #5742:  #5b3_hor a:   .add-topic-form #5742:  #5b3_k,
     dd-topic-form #574k,
-(..
     margin-top: 5px;
   }
idth: 90%;5%   }

   .add-topic-form .toll-votday     dd-topic-form #574e-ho
     margin-top: 5p;
   }

   .add-topic-form .tite-ho
     display: block;
   }

   .add-topic-form .titerror
     margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
ackground-color: #FED6FE6E
     padding: 20px;
     text-align: center;
   }
```

And the same kind of mess happens until the end of the CSS file. If anyone has met such a behavior before and know possible reasons - please, let me know.

**UPD:**

Thanks to all who answered. Found out that the problem was not only in IE, but in all browsers. Probably it was cache used in all except IE, that is why I misinterpret that the problem was in IE.

So finally I fixed the problem by using the other parameters for archiving in 7z. I used before Vocabulary size: 32Kb, Word length: 32 and it was working fine until the todays update. So I changed the parameter Word length to 16 and it fixed the problem. I'm not sure why it is not working with 32, maybe something was changed on the hoster side, because it was always working fine before. If anyone have an idea - please, put a comment. The problem is solved, but it would be great to understand what changed in the environment that created a problem.
PS on the local machine it was working fine as earlier, so the problem appeared only on the pro environment.

Comment: Can you add a link to the production site?

Comment: That looks really strange... What do you mean by "download through IE", using the debugger? It could look like it's some kind of proprietary encoding of unicode or some internal reference.

Comment: the site is beauty-review.ru, the problem appears only in IE, all the rest browsers are working fine.  By downloading from IE - I mean I just go to the css file address and download it through the browser.

Comment: have you got a doctype at the top of your HTML? without it, IE will drop into quirks mode, which will utterly mangle any CSS-based layout.

Comment: yes, the doctype is declared: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: can you provide a link directly the the CSS file, please?

Comment: http://beauty-review.ru/css/main.20110620.css

Comment: @Volder: I've just opened that CSS URL as plain text in Firefox, and I can tell you that the code is completely mashed up. I don't know what you've done to it, but it's a miracle it works anywhere. This is not an IE problem.

Comment: @Spudley, thanks I have not checked the file in the other browsers, while the appearence was ok there. Now I see that there is something woring with the file, but not with IE. Thanks for help, have no idea what has influenced in such a way, but going to check. The file css on the server is ok. Something wrong happens when it is sent to the user((

Comment: The file is mangled on the server. Have you tried simply deleting the file and re-uploading it. Drop any compression; just upload a simple plain text CSS file and see if it comes right.

Comment: the uncompressed file was on the server - it was always all right, the problem was in the compression, I changed parameters of the compression (described in the update of the topic) and it worked fine. But still don't get what was exactly producing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that way in Opera, Chrome and Firefox on my (linux) machine too. It's not related to IE. The css must have been messed up somehow on the server.

There's quite a few `-` symbols in the css making me think of a diff output. Could there have been a merge that have been incorrectly committed?

If that link looks okay to you, there must be something terribly wrong with the encoding (although I cannot get how an encoding error could cause the effect we're seeing).

Comment: yes, I have found that the same error repeats in the rest browsers as well. The problem seems to be with the archiving (gzipped version only), but I don't get what exactly. There are two version of css on the server main.nogzip.css - is not gzipped, and it is fine. The gzipped version I get manually, now I'm downloading the latest archivator version. I suppose that there was something on the hoster side changed as the same gzipped version of file works correctly on the local version of the site, if you have any ideas - please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Without any other information, my first thought is compression gone wrong. Check your compression/gzip settings on your server and see if it's sending compressed to IE. I know IE6 doesn't play well with gzip compression. It's worth checking, at least.

Another thing you could try (and yes, it sounds dumb, but sometimes it works) is to retype the offending lines (start with the first one that fails) and see if that fixes things. Sometimes, a stray invisible character gets thrown in and screws with things.

**Edit** - I noticed your response comments, as well as your domain name. Try setting the character set in your CSS file using the `@charset` rule. You might have to play around with the character sets to get it right, though I'd start with `@charset "utf-8"`. It's possible your local machine is running with an incompatible (or just different) character set to your server and that's where the issues are stemming from.

Comment: the problem appears with IE8 as well, which is kinda modern browser compared to IE6. And there is no automatic compression on the server side. The css file is compressed manually once, anyway I will check the compression-gzip stuff, thanks.

Comment: Good tip, I had this problem with a character that wasn't encoded properly in IE and it threw everything off. +1

Comment: retyped the characters - didn't help, seems to be some problem with the archiving, but still don't get what is wrong

Comment: @Volder - Did you see my edit? I thought of something else worth looking into.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like you might have found the issue is indeed with the compression.